# Capture string in repeating value

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture a in a repeating string, My string comes in like this:

```
L2:domain\usernameAL2:domain\usernameBL2:domain\usernameC etc..
```

it can go on for awhile.

My question is what regex can I use to capture `UsernameA`?

And if I wanted to, is it possible to capture `Domain\UsernameA`?

Comment: Which programming language you were using over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will specifically give you both the domain and username values **for the string** you have shown.

```
[(a-z)|(A-Z)]*[\\][(A-Z)|(a-z)(0-9)]*
```

Check link for proof.I've appended a set of extra characters for testing it as well:[link](https://regex101.com/r/cI8gD4/4)

Comment: Thanks! that was very accurate!! Much appreciated